# Cournot game and Bertrand game: Are they classes of game?

Tags: game-theory

Can we use the term "Cournot Game" to describe a competition with output quantity in general? Or, does "Cournot Game" only refer to the game studied by Cournot? For example, if we study a *dynamic* competition on output quantity, but with very different price functions and some added constraints, can we say it is a Cournot game?

Similarly, can we use the term "Bertrand Game" to describe a competition with price in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely treat (and name) a game in quantities, whether static or dynamic, as a Cournot game. Opting to do so is not wrong, nor inaccurate. A game whose strategy space consists of profiles in quantities was first studied by Cournot in the 19th century, hence he deserves some credit.

Some people use the term "Cournot-Nash", i.e. by treating equivalently the "Cournot" solution of a game to the Nash solution of a game. Evidently, a Nash solution is a broader concept - the equilibrium in Bertrand (price) competition is a Nash equilibrium of the game.

One of the most famous examples of a dynamic Cournot game that is both rich and very easy to read is the uber-classic paper by [Levhari and Mirman (1981)](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3003416) (see also [this version](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053105002097) that uses the [Benhabib-Rustichini](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165188994900329) trick to obtain a closed-form solution).